# How to begin learning CakePHP or any other MVC framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, cakephp, symfony1

I want to learn some MVC framework. I am trying to learn CakePHP by reading the docs on their website. But I am finding it very difficult to learn it.

Can someone suggest a good way to begin learning CakePHP and provide some alternative websites?

Comment: You've seen their list of documentation right? http://book.cakephp.org/view/9/Where-to-Get-Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're anything like me, you will only learn so much from reading; it's important to have a project. Find something you want to actually *build*. Even if it's the ubiquitous blog application, it's something with a definitive set of requirements that are reasonably well known--at least to you. If you're an experienced enough as a developer, you should have a pretty decent idea of what you *want* to do and from there it's just a matter of determining the (Cake|Rails|Django|etc.) way of doing that particular thing. Take it one thing at a time and eventually everything will click.

Pick a framework with an active (and helpful community). Leverage the documentation and that community extensively to help you get over the learning curve. There will be a learning curve and you *will* get discouraged from time to time. If you can power through, you'll be better for it.

It's rather generic advice, I know, but it's a rather high level question. Hopefully it helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Some pages that could give you a good start:

- [Bakery Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/219/Blog) - a simple blog that covers the basic principles .. this one gives you a guided project
- [IBM developerWorks tutorial 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/opensource/libraryview.jsp?search_by=cook+web+sites+CakePHP) - as the next one this is a bit out of date but helped me a lot
- [IBM developerWorks tutorial 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/opensource/libraryview.jsp?search_by=production+Wiki+PHP) - build a wiki
- [my delicious cake bookmarks](http://delicious.com/harpax/cakephp) - well .. you might as well look it up there

Answer (score 0):

tart doing something...only by practicing you will get something to know

try to do a blog, and you will use these techniques in every your project

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony's Askeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/) (now published as the "Practical symfony" book and still online for free) is designed to introduce the concepts and features in a hands-on way with "24 tutorials of 1 hour each".  I would guess it would work to pick up many of the general MVC concepts too.

Answer (score 0):

I started to learn CakePHP around 2 months ago, and then jumped (hit the ground running on a large Cake PHP project). The way I have found to learn Cake is to read EVERY (relevant) article around, as well as the 4 books in Print. Spefically I would read 'Cakephp Application development' first as that book seems to be best 'all-rounder'.